# bootstrap hidden-lg class is not working in ie9

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

Bootstrap hidden-lg class is not working in IE 9

hidden-lg is not hiding the specified element in IE 9 only.

Anyone know this issue ?

Comment: is it working on all other browser ?

Comment: Shajeer, Yes including IE10 and and IE11 all browsers it is working.

Answer (score 0):

for using bootstrap in IE 9 you have to add respond.js and html5shiva.js,other wise media queries wont work. you might be missing these things, please correct your page and check

```
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
```

**HTML**

```
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

bootstrap clearly explains this [click to read](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)

read [this](http://www.joostrap.com/blog/bootstrap-3-supporting-internet-explorer-8-and-9) link also

Hope this works fine

Comment: Hi Shajeer, I have already added shim, respond, but it is not working

Comment: Hi Shajeer, I got the issue but not the fix ie., when i flip the code in bootstrap.css hidden-md to hidden-lg, then hidden-lg is working and hidden-md is not working.

Comment: @KSSS can you paste here what is written in hidden-lg in your bootstrap.css

Comment: I got the fix, IE9 it supports only fixed number of css rules, thats why it is not working from hidden-lg, Thank you for your time..